# How to download HTML Report from HP ALM Performance Center 11.0 using rest API

Tags: hp-quality-center, hp-performance-center

I want to download HTML default report for a test run from Performance Center storage (using Rest API). Actually I need just **summary.html** file.

I was using the following steps in PC 11.5:

- Request test scenarios:

  > http://{server:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/tests?fields=id,last-modified,name,owner&query={subtype-id[=PERFORMANCE-TEST]}&page-size=max
- Let user choose the scenario (id) and request all its runs:

  > http://{server:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/runs?page-size=max&fields=id,owner,pc-start-time,duration,status,test-id&query={test-id[=234]}
- Let user choose the run (id) and request Report (result entity):

  > http://{server:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/results?page-size=max&query={run-id[=123];name[=Reports]}&fields=id,name
- Request "summary.html" file using file-id taken from previous step response:

  > http://{server:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/results/{file-id}/storage/report/summary.html

However it is not working with Performance Center 11.0. It fails at last step:
qccore.general-error
Not Found

I guess it is because the path of report was changed.

Can someone tell the path for **summary.html** for Performance Center 11.0?

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to have a little bit of success with this. Rather than use the request you are using above I used the following:

```
http://{server:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/results/{file-id}/logical-storage/
```

This gave me a zip file, which contained the report inside it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I have tried to get just summary.html file but did not succeed. So your solution is the best now.

Comment: don't you know btw how to upload the test script file and all data it uses?

Comment: I haven't as of yet been able to do that but it is something im actively looking into as my end goal is to completely automate the deployment of test scripts. I believe it should be possible with the API.

Comment: After two days of research I haven't find the way to do it. Script storage has read-only access using REST API, but we can do it with the old COM OTA API.

Comment: @lua.rasta we've discovered the same thing and ultimately have ended up writing our client to utilise both the REST and OTA APIs (via Com4j in our case). This seems to work for us, but is a bit more clunky than i'd like